# Transaction description and app name not showing with PayPal REST API

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am using PayPal Payments REST API to accept payments on some website.
Just now I noticed that both the transaction description as well as the app name (which you configure in developer dashboard) are no longer displayed. Why is this? Some recent change? Or something with my account?

It is very bad as I have a single company PayPal account which I use for various websites and the app name & transaction description is to give the corresponding payment flows their own identity. Currently people abort payments because they don't understand why the details in the payment overview on PayPal are completely different/unrelated from where they initiated payment.

Please see image below for what I mean.

If anyone can confirm this is happening for everyone now and/or refer to some PayPal documentation/statement regarding this topic then please share. I could not find anything on PayPal developer resources.

[image: PayPal payment screen issues]

Comment: Did you make any progress with this? I am encountering similar issues..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display a 'custom' name, you need to create a custom 'Web experience profile'.

I was utilising the PHP SDK so did so by following their [sample code](http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/payment-experience/CreateWebProfile.html).

You can also create a 'Web experience profile' with a direct request to the relevant API endpoint.

Once you have created the profile you simply set the identifier on the `Payment` object (PHP) like so:

```
$payment->setIntent("sale")
            ->setPayer($payer)
            ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
            ->setTransactions(array($transaction))
            ->setExperienceProfileId($this->config->paypal->experienceId);
```

Comment: Thanks; had also come to this conclusion but didn't have time to actually implement & test this yet. So props go to your answer :)